# How to find a file name inside directoryphp

Tags: php, regex, glob

I woul try to develop a function to find an element of file name inside a directory.

Is it possible ?
name of file : apps_module_name.json

search request could be for example : a or apps or name

I think the glob function must be use ?
I tried this

`%$file_name%` : is wrong but is something like mysql search than I am looking.

```
 $result = glob(OSCOM::getConfig('dir_root', 'Shop') . $this->ModuleInfosJson . '/' . %$file_name . '.json');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk `*` matches all. Not `%`. Correct code will be.

```
$result = glob(OSCOM::getConfig('dir_root', 'Shop') . $this->ModuleInfosJson . '/*' . $file_name . '*.json');
```

It matches `AnythingFilenameAnything.json`

Eg:

`glob("a*.php")` will match

```
a.php 
aa.php 
ab.php  
abc.php
```